# consolidate selectors in CSS / SCSS

Tags: css, regex, sass, sublimetext2

I would like to convert a syntax of this manner (just an example):

```
a{ 
    width:100px; 
    height:120px;
    &:hover{ 
        color:red; 
    }
    span{ 
        color:blue; 
        padding:10px;
        i{ 
            color:red; 
        }
    }
}
```

To a syntax like this (which I find more readable, but please lets no argue of why it's my choice...)

```
a{ width:100px; height:120px;
    &:hover{ color:red; }
    span{ color:blue; padding:10px;
        i{ color:red; }
    }
}
```

I was trying for an some time, googlng, investigating different REGEX methods..but since my REGEX skills are almost zero, i had to try stuff i've found online, but with no success. Basically this is for some Sublime plugin that I am writing, or trying to write, because doin't it manually for files is just too much work..but I can only work like this. (OCD).

Maybe there is a tool online, which I don't know of, which does this type of beautification?

Comment: As a 9K user you should know that asking to find a tool is off-topic here. You could maybe try at [Software Recommendations SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @HamZa - well I'm more interested in the REGEX itself, I just mentioned that if there's a tool it would be also great to know it exist. But i choose to write here in Stackoverflow because there are much more developers here, so the chances are somebody knows the answer are statistically higher, while also, this is a very important topic in the CSS world, and I hope others will see this thread.

Comment: RegEx is not terribly good at recursion.

Comment: well, maybe not in a single pass of Regex search & replace, but a combination..

Comment: @vsync It seems that this pattern does the job for the *current* input `(?<=[;{])\s+(?!.*?\{)`, replace with a space. [**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/gZ6cJ3). Could you test it further ?

Comment: @HamZa - cool! but why does it pastes the output as one line if I copy everything? also, this Regex seems to work only for `PHP` settings or `Python`... it doesn't find anything on my texteditor for example

Comment: @vsync `why does it pastes the output as one line if I copy everything?` I'm not sure what you're talking about. Also what editor are you using ? I tested this in Notepad++ and I expect it to work in SublimeText. Do not forget to enable the regex option. Do not expect this regex to work in all engines since the syntax/capability may differ

Comment: yeah I forgot to chose Regex in Notepad++, you're right. I use both Sublime and Notepad++ by the way. great REGEX btw, really awesome. The thing I mentioned about the copy-paste output is related to that demo page you put a link to, that If I select the output text and paste it in a text editor, it is outputted as a single line

Comment: so, you can write your regex as the answer to this post, and I'll pick it as the right one.